# WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified, cannot resolve in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have made a Python program which will clean up the unnecessary names present in my downloaded torrent files+folders, so that I can upload it to my unlimited Google Drive Storage Account without much hassle.

However, it gives me the: `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified` after certain number of iterations.**If I run the program again, it works fine for a certain iterations and then the same error pops up.**

Note that I have taken precautions using `os.path.join` to avoid this error but it keeps coming up. Because of this error, I have to run the program tens of times over a selected folder/drive.

Here is my program:

```
import os
terms = ("-LOL[ettv]" #Other terms removed
)
#print terms[0]
p = "E:\TV Series"
for (path,dir,files) in os.walk(p):
    for name in terms:
        for i in files:
            if name in i:
                print i
                fn,_,sn = i.rpartition(name)
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
        for i in dir:
            if name in i:
                print i
                fn,_,sn = i.rpartition(name)
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
```

And the Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\abcd.py", line 22, in <module>
os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's the problem with subdirectories due to the way `os.walk` works, namely `path` on next iteration after the first with subdirectories. `os.walk` gathers subdirectories' names to visit on further iterations on it's first iteration in current directory...

E.g., on first call to `os.walk` you get:

```
('.', ['dir1', 'dir2'], ['file1', 'file2'])
```

now you rename the files (this works ok), and you rename: `'dir1'` to `'dirA'` and `'dir2'` to `'dirB'`.

On next iteration of `os.walk`, you get:

```
('dir1', ['subdir1-2', 'subdir1-2'], ['file1-1', 'file1-2'])
```

And what happens here is there's no `'dir1'` anymore, as it is already renamed on the file system, but `os.walk` still remembers it's old name in the list inside and gives it to you. Now, when you try to rename `'file1-1'` you ask for `'dir1/file1-1'`, but on the file system it's actually is `'dirA/file1-1'` and you get the error.

To solve this issue, you need to change the values in the list that is used by `os.walk` on further iterations, e.g. in your code:

```
for (path, dir, files) in os.walk(p):
    for name in terms:
        for i in files:
            if name in i:
                print i
                fn, _, sn = i.rpartition(name)
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
        for i in dir:
            if name in i:
                print i
                fn, _, sn = i.rpartition(name)
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
                #here remove the old name and put a new name in the list
                #this will break the order of subdirs, but it doesn't
                #break the general algorithm, though if you need to keep
                #the order use '.index()' and '.insert()'.
                dirs.remove(i)
                dirs.append(fn+sn)
```

This should do the trick and in described above scenario, will lead to...

On first call to `os.walk`:

```
('.', ['dir1', 'dir2'], ['file1', 'file2'])
```

now rename: `'dir1'` to `'dirA'` and `'dir2'` to `'dirB'` and change the list as shown above... Now, on next iteration of `os.walk` it should be:

```
('dirA', ['subdir1-2', 'subdir1-2'], ['file1-1', 'file1-2'])
```

Comment: Yes!! This was the answer I expected. I already solved it an hour ago after guessing the problem(this was the tough part), the solving didn't took much time, all I did was use `enumerate` and edit the index of the `dir` renamed directory.

Comment: By the way, after I guessed the error, I posted an another question on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683291/how-to-update-current-directories-in-the-list-of-os-walk-while-renaming-it-in-re) where I update the post with an answer.