# How to update current directories in the list of os.walk while renaming it in real time

Tags: python, python-2.7

This was my original question: [Windows Error [Error 2]: The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681113/windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-cannot-resolv)

I seem to have found the issue regarding this error on this particular program that I wrote, and I am going to explain it down below:

What it does in the program is, it will rename files and directories during `os.walk` of some particular path. So, let's say I have renamed the directory successfully, **but the `name` of the directory that `os.walk` contains in it's list would still be the older one and not the one that I just renamed, and thus, the error while visiting the older directory name(which doesn't exist).** So, how do I solve this issue of updating the directories list that `os.walk` contains in real time. I hope I have conveyed the question in an understandable manner, and please refer to the above link for more details.

Here is the program for reference:

```
import os
terms = ( "-LOL[ettv]" #Other terms removed
)
#print terms[0]
p = "E:\TV Series"
for (path,dir,files) in os.walk(p):
    for name in terms:
        for i in files:
            if name in i:
                print i
                fn,_,sn = i.rpartition(name)
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
        for i in dir:
            if name in i:
                print i
                fn,_,sn = i.rpartition(name)
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
```

And the Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\abcd.py", line 22, in <module>
os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

**Update:** I solved it by changing the inner for-loops to this:

```
for j,i in enumerate(files):
        if name in i:
            print i
            fn,_,sn = i.rpartition(name)
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
            files[j] = fn+sn
for j,i in enumerate(dir):
        if name in i:
            print i
            fn,_,sn = i.rpartition(name)
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, fn+sn))
            dir[j] = fn+sn
```

Comment: Possibly, at the beginning of the `for (path,dir,files) in os.walk(p):`, put `path = os.path.join([newdir] + path.split(os.pathsep))`?

Comment: @zondo Can you explain what it does?

Comment: `path.split(os.pathsep)` creates a list containing all of the different folders in the path.  For example, `"folder/sub"` would become `["folder", "sub"]`.  I then add to that list the new directory path.  I didn't actually tell you the right thing because it should be `path.split(os.pathsep)[1:])` so as to remove the first directory.  That `1` should be however many directories deep you want to change it.  For example, moving from `"/home/user/f"` to `"/home/user/r"`, if you were currently working on `"/home/user/f/r"`, you would want to remove only `"/home/user/f"` which is 4 folders deep.

Comment: @zondo dude, with that much in the comments, just make an answer already. :P dooo it.

Comment: @zondo I actually didn't understood, but I solved the problem, using `enumerate`, what I did to solve it was change the `for loop`(for both dir and files) to this: (Check updated question)

Comment: That's great.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @zondo There's nothing to be sorry about. You gave a right answer, to a different question.